# UnityVR - Having the both renders display the exact same image for each eye

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

When Unity builds a VR project, by default it is set to make the two views stereoscopic. It slightly offsets the camera position of one eye to give the user a sense of depth.

For example a square will appear slightly to the left on the right view compared to the left view.

I want to make the camera truly monoscopic by removing the offset that is created when i build the project. Each camera should render all objects in exactly the same position for both eyes.

One of things i tried was creating two camera and setting them to the left and right eye. Then i manually set the position/rotation of one camera until it looked monoscopic

It worked fine on my pixel phone, but as soon as i put the project on my test phone i noticed that the difference in resolutions messed up the view i was going for. The blocks were not in the same position when i looked at both renders.

If anyone has any solutions or ideas as to how i can go about this, i would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: One idea i had considered was taking either the left or right camera render and mirroring it to the other eye camera. But i dont really know where to start with that...

Comment: Try to set the scale of the camera to very small - or the world's scale to very big. Then, both eyes will see basically the same image.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use 2 cameras, but instead of offsetting them, you can just make the width of the camera half.

Make 2 cameras, set their positions to exactly the same.

On the left eye camera, set the width to 0.5 and the x position to 0.

On the right eye camera, set the width to 0.5 and the x position to 0.5.

[image]

You should now have 2 cameras rendering the exact same thing, but twice across the screen, with no sense of depth.